# Django - Appending dictionary values return empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary, django-views

I have a list of words, called `lyrics_sorted`, that looks like this:

`lyrics_sorted = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', ]`

Now I want to make a dictionary with this as one of the keys, and another key the normalized form of the word.

So first I declare the key values, like this:

```
word_original = lyrics_sorted
word_normalized = []
```

And then the dictionary:

```
grammar_dict = {'word_original': word_original, 'word_normalized': word_normalized}
```

And now for every word in `word_original` (or `lyrics_sorted`), I want to add the normalized form, so I do as follows:

```
for word in lyrics_sorted:
    w = morph.parse(word)[0]
    word_normalized.append(w.normal_form)

    context['grammar_dict'] = list(zip(grammar_dict['word_original'],
                                       grammar_dict['word_normalized'],))
return context
```

But I get just an empty list. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong; when I test it in the shell it works.

Comment: You’re adding a list of word pairs to your context not a dict, is that intentional?

Comment: @IainShelvington Well, the end result that I want is to be able to make a table with two columns, where column 1 shows `word1` and column 2 shows the normalized form of `word1`. Am I doing it wrong? I used this in a previous code and it worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with this setup.

```
class MyView(...):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lyrics_sorted = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', ]
        grammar_list = []
        for word in lyrics_sorted:
            parsed_word = morph.parse(word)[0]
            result = {
                'word_original': word,
                'word_normalized': parsed_word.normal_form
            }
            grammar_list.append(result)

            context['grammar_list'] = grammar_list
        return context
```

So, the `grammar_list` will look like

```
[
    {'word_original': 'word1', 'word_normalized': 'word1_normalized'},
    {'word_original': 'word2', 'word_normalized': 'word2_normalized'},
    {'word_original': 'word3', 'word_normalized': 'word3_normalized'},
]
```

hence, you can access the **`grammar_list`** context variable in your Django template as,

```
{% for item in grammar_list %}
    {{ item.word_original }} ---- {{ item.word_normalized }}
{% endfor %}
```